# Is there any option in Highcharts for simplifyng a line graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I´m setting up a preview for a graph, and I want to know if highcharts has any option for reducing the number of points showed in a series. I have points everyday in 5 years, and I would like to reduce for a simple preview. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of points by your own function, but I think that the best solution will be to use provided by Highstock `dataGrouping` feature:

```
series: [{
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true
    },
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ky0s2oh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping